# Angular Kendo UI Data Grid populate from service

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using this [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/) to lean Kendo Grid with Angular 6. I want to get data from service instead of import from a ts file.

I have created a service and called it from ngOnIt() hook as below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("In ngOnInit method");
    this._reportService.getreports().subscribe(
              results => {this.gridDataVal = results; },
              error => this.errorMessage =<any> error
          );}

public state: State = {
    skip: 0,
    take: 5,
    // Initial filter descriptor
    filter: {
      logic: 'and',
      filters: [{ field: 'reportName', operator: 'contains', value: 'test' }]
    }
};

public gridData: GridDataResult = process(this.gridDataVal, this.state);

public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    this.gridData = process(this.gridDataVal, this.state);
}
```

`gridDataVal`  is the [data] for the grid.

```
<div *ngIf="gridDataVal">
<kendo-grid  
             [resizable]="true" 
             [data]="gridData" 
             [skip]="state.skip"
             [sort]="state.sort"
             [filter]="state.filter"
             [height]="600"
             [filterable]="true"
             [sortable]="true"
             (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
             >
  <kendo-grid-column field="date" title="Date"  width="30" filter="date" format="{0:d}">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportName" title="Report Name" width="80">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportLink" title="Report Link" width="80"> 
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" [href]="dataItem.reportLink">{{dataItem.reportLink}}</a>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportStatus" title="Report Status" width="40">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="region" title="Region" width="40">
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
</div>
```

I get error as `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. When I hard code gridDataVal with values, everything works fine. 
is there something wrong with the way I am calling service? I tried *ngIf directive as well. Code does not even hit ngOnIt method.

Any ideas or pointers ? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the populating of your gridData to the response from the API, like so:

```
public gridData: GridDataResult; 

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("In ngOnInit method");
    this._reportService.getreports().subscribe(
              results => {
                  this.gridDataVal = results; 
                  this.gridData = process(this.gridDataVal, this.state);
              },
              error => this.errorMessage =<any> error
          );}
```